# Filter rows based on growing season time period in r

Tags: r, filter

I am struggling to find a solution.

I have the following gridded samples datasets (I paste different portions of my dataset)

```
First one: structure(list(gid = c("117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
    "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
    "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
    "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765"), 
        country = c("Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)"
        ), Time = structure(c(3667, 3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 3819, 
        3849, 3880, 3911, 3941, 3972, 4002, 4033, 4063, 4092, 4123, 
        4153, 4184, 4214, 4245, 4276, 4306, 4337, 4367), class = "Date"), 
        Month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
        "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
        "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"), SPEI1 = c(-0.702853560447693, 
        2.77506303787231, -1.38380765914917, -0.474617034196854, 
        0.610002398490906, -0.389719426631927, 2.31887650489807, 
        1.47994863986969, 1.66277933120728, 0.399970233440399, -1.47139978408813, 
        -0.435711354017258, -0.510784149169922, -1.15937781333923, 
        0.523077189922333, -0.161062479019165, -0.481528997421265, 
        -1.71726500988007, -1.77663195133209, 0.765306115150452, 
        -0.774405002593994, -0.197176232933998, -1.47615599632263, 
        -0.388415157794952), growstart = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 10, 10), growend = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), maincrop = c(28, 
        28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
        28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28)), row.names = 572161:572184, class = "data.frame")
```

_

```
Second one = structure(list(gid = c("100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468"), 
    country = c("Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
    "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
    "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
    "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
    "Namibia"), Time = structure(c(3667, 3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 
    3819, 3849, 3880, 3911, 3941, 3972, 4002, 4033, 4063, 4092, 
    4123, 4153, 4184, 4214, 4245, 4276, 4306, 4337, 4367), class = "Date"), 
    SPEI1 = c(-1.95947802066803, 0.557283878326416, 1.77989518642426, 
    -1.2029390335083, -0.119278997182846, 1.44610369205475, -1.4578732252121, 
    -1.14002466201782, 1.1647777557373, -1.34318947792053, -0.500527501106262, 
    1.50793671607971, -1.45792877674103, -2.00679230690002, -1.51340460777283, 
    -1.9636687040329, -1.40127754211426, -0.182968750596046, 
    0.295145452022552, 0.630711793899536, -0.166128441691399, 
    -0.55840003490448, -2.62139987945557, -1.74482023715973), 
    growstart = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), growend = c(4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4), maincrop = c(52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
    52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
    52), Month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
    "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
    "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12")), row.names = 385:408, class = "data.frame")
```

_

```
Third one: structure(list(gid = c("117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770"), 
    country = c("Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)"
    ), Time = structure(c(3667, 3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 3819, 
    3849, 3880, 3911, 3941, 3972, 4002, 4033, 4063, 4092, 4123, 
    4153, 4184, 4214, 4245, 4276, 4306, 4337, 4367), class = "Date"), 
    SPEI1 = c(0.649401307106018, 1.423499584198, -2.04273128509521, 
    0.271935135126114, 0.616238355636597, -1.03605198860168, 
    1.6733535528183, 1.78166878223419, 1.87084305286407, 1.10145688056946, 
    -1.23061907291412, -1.64128601551056, -1.00736439228058, 
    -1.91670513153076, 1.09841585159302, 0.464365869760513, 1.01759243011475, 
    -1.08844792842865, -0.508061945438385, -0.196570366621017, 
    -0.805905878543854, 0.117944374680519, -0.862984955310822, 
    -1.63738548755646), growstart = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), growend = c(12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), maincrop = c(37, 37, 37, 
    37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
    37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37), Month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", 
    "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", 
    "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"
    )), row.names = 574081:574104, class = "data.frame")
```

I have a column 'main crop'that indicates the main crop in my cell (gid) and the growing season months (growstart and growend).

Example in the first sample:
For crop 28, the starting growing month is 10(October from the previous year) and it ends in 1(January from the following year).

So, I will only get the rows between 1980-10-16 and 1981-01-16.

**I would like to select for each cell (gid) the rows values according to the growing season.**

Please note that I have a dataframe of more than 3 millions observations and different type of crops/growing season. Hence the 3 samples.

I would really appreciate an automated way to get what I want.

Thank you !!

PS: 10 coffees for the helper that would save my sanity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to extract based on values of the Month column that are in the set {10:12, 1}. See if this use of the "[" operator with a logical expression using %in% is satisfactory. (I'm assuming the data structure is named `dz` In the first code example but named `dat` In the second function application. )

I hope we can assume that within a particular gid and crop grouping that all the start and end values are the same, so we can group by those two columns and then pick the start and end values from the first row of each group. Here is the general approach (that is specific you your example but won't be if you expand it to include other crop and growing season values:

```
 lapply( split(dz, paste(dz$gid, dz$maincrop)),
         function(gcdz){ gcdz[ gcdz$Month %in% c(10:12, "01"), ]})
$`117765 28`
          gid                               country       Time Month      SPEI1 growstart growend maincrop
572161 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-01-16    01 -0.7028536        10       1       28
572170 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-10-16    10  0.3999702        10       1       28
572171 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-11-16    11 -1.4713998        10       1       28
572172 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-12-16    12 -0.4357114        10       1       28
572173 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-01-16    01 -0.5107841        10       1       28
572182 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-10-16    10 -0.1971762        10       1       28
572183 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-11-16    11 -1.4761560        10       1       28
572184 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-12-16    12 -0.3884152        10       1       28
```

Now we need to add code to that function that uses the start and end values in row 1 and (a) delivers character values with leading zeros if needed, and (b) decides whether we are wrapping around the first of the year.

EDIT: I made a list of those dataframe structures and used:

```
# to create a single dataframe with the common column names
dat2 <- do.call(rbind, dat)
```

The added the code to accomplish the tasks outlined above.

```
 lapply( split(dat2, paste(dat2$gid, dat2$maincrop)),
          function(gcdz){ # need  seq(start, end) in 2 char format and allow for wrap around
                    if( gcdz$growstart[1] > gcdz$growend[1]){ 
           sqnc <- c( gcdz$growstart[1]:12, 1: gcdz$growend[1])} else {
           sqnc <- gcdz$growstart[1]: gcdz$growend[1] }
         sqnct <- sprintf("%02s",sqnc )
 
         gods[ gcdz$Month %in% sqnct, ] # select rows in grow-seq
        } # complete function def
   ). # complete lapply call
```

This will be returned as a list of distinct dataframes

```
#-------------results----------
$`100468 52`
       gid country       Time Month      SPEI1 growstart growend maincrop
385 100468 Namibia 1980-01-16    01 -1.9594780        12       4       52
386 100468 Namibia 1980-02-15    02  0.5572839        12       4       52
387 100468 Namibia 1980-03-16    03  1.7798952        12       4       52
388 100468 Namibia 1980-04-16    04 -1.2029390        12       4       52
396 100468 Namibia 1980-12-16    12  1.5079367        12       4       52
397 100468 Namibia 1981-01-16    01 -1.4579288        12       4       52
398 100468 Namibia 1981-02-15    02 -2.0067923        12       4       52
399 100468 Namibia 1981-03-16    03 -1.5134046        12       4       52
400 100468 Namibia 1981-04-16    04 -1.9636687        12       4       52
408 100468 Namibia 1981-12-16    12 -1.7448202        12       4       52

$`117765 28`
          gid                               country       Time Month      SPEI1 growstart
572161 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-01-16    01 -0.7028536        10
572170 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-10-16    10  0.3999702        10
572171 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-11-16    11 -1.4713998        10
572172 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-12-16    12 -0.4357114        10
572173 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-01-16    01 -0.5107841        10
572182 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-10-16    10 -0.1971762        10
572183 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-11-16    11 -1.4761560        10
572184 117765 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-12-16    12 -0.3884152        10
       growend maincrop
572161       1       28
572170       1       28
572171       1       28
572172       1       28
572173       1       28
572182       1       28
572183       1       28
572184       1       28

$`117770 37`
          gid                               country       Time Month      SPEI1 growstart
574085 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-05-16    05  0.6162384         5
574086 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-06-16    06 -1.0360520         5
574087 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-07-16    07  1.6733536         5
574088 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-08-16    08  1.7816688         5
574089 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-09-16    09  1.8708431         5
574090 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-10-16    10  1.1014569         5
574091 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-11-16    11 -1.2306191         5
574092 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1980-12-16    12 -1.6412860         5
574097 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-05-16    05  1.0175924         5
574098 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-06-16    06 -1.0884479         5
574099 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-07-16    07 -0.5080619         5
574100 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-08-16    08 -0.1965704         5
574101 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-09-16    09 -0.8059059         5
574102 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-10-16    10  0.1179444         5
574103 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-11-16    11 -0.8629850         5
574104 117770 Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire) 1981-12-16    12 -1.6373855         5
       growend maincrop
574085      12       37
574086      12       37
574087      12       37
574088      12       37
574089      12       37
574090      12       37
574091      12       37
574092      12       37
574097      12       37
574098      12       37
574099      12       37
574100      12       37
574101      12       37
574102      12       37
574103      12       37
574104      12       37
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. Unfortunately as mentioned in the post, I have a dataset with more than 3mi observations whit different crops and growing seasons. So, your code cannot work.

Comment: I have outlined a way forward. It's potential for success now depends on you using the [edit] facilities to make your example into a testable [MCVE] case.

Comment: alright. I updated my post with 3 different samples. Is that ok now ?

Comment: It took extra time to complete the MCVE. The use of `sprintf` to make the numeric month sequence agree in format with the "month" leading zero format follows one of the examples in `?sprintf`.

Comment: Its alight, I got my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838494/filter-by-months-when-overlapping-two-years-in-r/72838989?noredirect=1#comment128741533_72838989

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
## Merging the datasets provided 
### Since yours is merged you can avoid this step
## Just assign your dataframe to df
df=rbind(df1,df2,df3)

## Creating a function to filter the crops growing season base on Month Start and Month End Date
CropTimePeriodFiltering = function(DateFrom, DateTo){
  DateFrom1 = match(DateFrom, month.name) ## growtstart
  DateFrom2 = match(DateTo, month.name) ## growend
  
  df_final=df %>%
    filter(DateFrom1<=growstart & DateFrom2>=growend)
  return(df_final)
}

## Using the function
CropTimePeriodFiltering(DateFrom = "July", DateTo = "December")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Does this response meet your requirement?

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying but I don't get how it resolve the problem. In your picture, for crop 28, it starts in month 10 (so October from the previous year 1980) and end in month 1 (so January from the following year). Do you see the corresponding rows in the time/month column in your example?