# Filter by months when overlapping two years in r

Tags: r, filter, subset, overlap

I am struggling to find a solution.

I have the following gridded samples datasets (I paste different parts of my dataset)

```
First one: structure(list(gid = c("117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
    "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
    "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
    "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765"), 
        country = c("Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
        "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)"
        ), Time = structure(c(3667, 3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 3819, 
        3849, 3880, 3911, 3941, 3972, 4002, 4033, 4063, 4092, 4123, 
        4153, 4184, 4214, 4245, 4276, 4306, 4337, 4367), class = "Date"), 
        Month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
        "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
        "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"), SPEI1 = c(-0.702853560447693, 
        2.77506303787231, -1.38380765914917, -0.474617034196854, 
        0.610002398490906, -0.389719426631927, 2.31887650489807, 
        1.47994863986969, 1.66277933120728, 0.399970233440399, -1.47139978408813, 
        -0.435711354017258, -0.510784149169922, -1.15937781333923, 
        0.523077189922333, -0.161062479019165, -0.481528997421265, 
        -1.71726500988007, -1.77663195133209, 0.765306115150452, 
        -0.774405002593994, -0.197176232933998, -1.47615599632263, 
        -0.388415157794952), growstart = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 10, 10), growend = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), maincrop = c(28, 
        28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
        28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28)), row.names = 572161:572184, class = "data.frame")
```

_

```
Second one = structure(list(gid = c("100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468"), 
    country = c("Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
    "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
    "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
    "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
    "Namibia"), Time = structure(c(3667, 3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 
    3819, 3849, 3880, 3911, 3941, 3972, 4002, 4033, 4063, 4092, 
    4123, 4153, 4184, 4214, 4245, 4276, 4306, 4337, 4367), class = "Date"), 
    SPEI1 = c(-1.95947802066803, 0.557283878326416, 1.77989518642426, 
    -1.2029390335083, -0.119278997182846, 1.44610369205475, -1.4578732252121, 
    -1.14002466201782, 1.1647777557373, -1.34318947792053, -0.500527501106262, 
    1.50793671607971, -1.45792877674103, -2.00679230690002, -1.51340460777283, 
    -1.9636687040329, -1.40127754211426, -0.182968750596046, 
    0.295145452022552, 0.630711793899536, -0.166128441691399, 
    -0.55840003490448, -2.62139987945557, -1.74482023715973), 
    growstart = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), growend = c(4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4), maincrop = c(52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
    52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
    52), Month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
    "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
    "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12")), row.names = 385:408, class = "data.frame")
```

_

```
Third one: structure(list(gid = c("117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770"), 
    country = c("Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
    "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)"
    ), Time = structure(c(3667, 3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 3819, 
    3849, 3880, 3911, 3941, 3972, 4002, 4033, 4063, 4092, 4123, 
    4153, 4184, 4214, 4245, 4276, 4306, 4337, 4367), class = "Date"), 
    SPEI1 = c(0.649401307106018, 1.423499584198, -2.04273128509521, 
    0.271935135126114, 0.616238355636597, -1.03605198860168, 
    1.6733535528183, 1.78166878223419, 1.87084305286407, 1.10145688056946, 
    -1.23061907291412, -1.64128601551056, -1.00736439228058, 
    -1.91670513153076, 1.09841585159302, 0.464365869760513, 1.01759243011475, 
    -1.08844792842865, -0.508061945438385, -0.196570366621017, 
    -0.805905878543854, 0.117944374680519, -0.862984955310822, 
    -1.63738548755646), growstart = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), growend = c(12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12), maincrop = c(37, 37, 37, 
    37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
    37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37), Month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", 
    "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", 
    "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"
    )), row.names = 574081:574104, class = "data.frame")
```

I have a column 'main crop' that indicates the main crop in my cell (gid) and the growing season months (growstart and growend).

**For each crop/gid/country/Time, I need to select the rows corresponding to the growing season.**

**The issue I am struggling with is that some growing season months overlap two years and I don't know how to filter based on this condition?**

**Example in the first sample (overlapping two years):**
For crop 28, the starting growing month is 10(October from the previous year) and it ends in 1(January from the following year).
So for this crop according to the gid/country/Time, I will  get the rows 1980-01-16 for year 1980 (because I don't have the data for 1979) and the rows between 1980-10-16 and 1981-01-16 for 1981.

**Example in the second sample (overlapping two years):**
For crop 52, the starting growing month is 12(December from the previous year) and it ends in 4(April from the following year).
So for this crop according to the gid/country/Time, I will only get the rows between 1980-01-16 and 1980-04-16 for year 1980 + the rows between 1980-12-16 and 1981-04-16 for 1981.

**Example in the second sample (no overlap):**
For crop 37, the starting growing month is 5(May of the current year) and it ends in 12(December of the current year).
I will only get the rows between 1980-05-16 and 1980-05-16 for year 1980 + between 1981-05-16 and 1981-12-16 for year 1981.

Please note that I have a dataframe of more than 3 millions observations and different type of crops/growing season. Hence the 3 samples.

I would really appreciate an automated way to get what I want.

Thank you !!

PS: 10 coffees for the helper that would save my sanity.

Comment: Create a second dataset with columns (say) gid, country, crop, seasonStart and seasonEnd. Join this dataset with your crop dataset and then filter to select the rows you want. You may need to join by time as well. You refer to both time and year, so I’m a little confused about the role each plays.

Comment: Have you looked at my dataset? why creating a second dataset in order to join it to my crop dataset while this is actually my initial dataset? Yes, the year within the Time column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to use `dplyr`, which allows you to group and filter. An important aspect then is the definition of the seasons, which depends on whether it is a season with or without overlap. It is important to note that this approach implicitly assumes that the growing season is constant at the gid, country and maincrop level.

I think one problem with your approach is also that the variable "Month" is stored as a character rather than a numeric variable, which does not allow you to subset the information properly.

In the following code, I have combined your three subsets of data into one `data.frame`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- rbind(one, two, three)
df$Month <- as.numeric(df$Month)

filtered_df <- df %>%
  group_by(gid, country, maincrop) %>%
  filter(Month %in% unique(ifelse(growend <= growstart,
                                  unique(c(seq(growstart[1], 12), seq(1, growend[1]))),
                                  seq(growstart[1], growend[1])))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! thank you very much!!! What if I want to create a second dataset with the month that do not correspond to the growing season?

Comment: @MyrTH great to here that is was helpful. In order to achieve this, simply add in the filter statement in front of Month an `!`, i.e., `filter(!Month %in% unique....)`. Thereby, `!` is the logical-NOT operator in R.

Comment: Super. Last question if I may ^^. If I want to get the mean of the value 'SPEI1' per growing season, what would I have to add ?

Comment: There are different options. Assuming that the growing season is indicated by your variable gid; you could use the following approach: `filtered_df %>% group_by(gid) %>% summarise(mean = mean(SPEI1, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% ungroup()`. This approach uses the df that is already filtered (based on the code above). If you want the summary stats by country you need to adjust the group_by statement accordingly. You could also directly incorporate the summarise statement after the filter statement ends i.e., after `%>%`, but then of course it would be based on the original df (given the code above).

Comment: Thank you! I would like to average the SPEI value per year. For the overlapping years, it would be assigned to the year corresponding to the end of the growing season. Example: from October 1981 to April 1982, it will be assigned to 1982 (year of the harvest).

Comment: @MyrTH If I understand you correctly, the following approach should work. You need to add the harvest year and then use the harvest year in the group_by statement to compute the summary statistics. You can add this statement after the filter statement as outlined above: `mutate(harvestYear =ifelse(growend <= growstart & Month %in% seq(growstart[1], 12), lubridate::year(Time) + 1, lubridate::year(Time)))`. This statement extracts the year from the Time column and adds +1 year for the obs. from the old year in an overlapping harvest period.

Comment: I got an error because of the NAs in my dataset (which I need to keep). Otherwise, if I bypass it by removing them and reintegrate them afterwards, it works. You are a genius. Thank you very much. Let me know which app to use for the coffees ;)

Comment: Last question (promise!). What would be the opposite to compute the SPEI mean value for the non-growing season? I tried different things but could get my desired results. It worked for one type of growing season but not another. For the overlapping years, it would be assigned to the year corresponding to the start of the growing season. Example: in harvest year 1981, the growing season is from October 1980 to April 1981. So, the non growing season for year 1981 would be from May 1980 to September 1980.

Comment: @MyrTH Simply filter your data based on the logical-NOT operator as outlined in my second comment and change the `mutate` statement as follows: `mutate(harvestYear =ifelse(growend <= growstart & lubridate::year(Time) > lubridate::year(Time[1]) , lubridate::year(Time)-1, lubridate::year(Time)))`

Comment: This is quite strange because it works for mostly all the years except for 1982. In 1982, for the overlapping growing seasons, it keeps the months from the same year. Not from 1981. However, for the other years, it's ok.

Comment: @MyrTH I can't see this issue in your data.

Comment: I put 2 examples here. The issue is with 1981 and 1982. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G7fjo3eQOVv7SHcxXQnvvcv1PL-QZdL8noCHc-b1wMM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Combined all into one `tibble`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

crops %>% 
  mutate(Month = month(Time)) %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Time), Overlap = growend - growstart < 0) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(
    (Overlap & !(Month %in% (growend+1):(growstart-1))) |
    (!Overlap & Month %in% growstart:growend)
  ) %>% 
  select(names(crops))
#> # A tibble: 34 × 8
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    gid    country             Time       Month  SPEI1 growstart growend maincrop
#>    <chr>  <chr>               <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 117765 Congo, Democratic … 1980-01-16     1 -0.703        10       1       28
#>  2 117765 Congo, Democratic … 1980-10-16    10  0.400        10       1       28
#>  3 117765 Congo, Democratic … 1980-11-16    11 -1.47         10       1       28
#>  4 117765 Congo, Democratic … 1980-12-16    12 -0.436        10       1       28
#>  5 117765 Congo, Democratic … 1981-01-16     1 -0.511        10       1       28
#>  6 117765 Congo, Democratic … 1981-10-16    10 -0.197        10       1       28
#>  7 117765 Congo, Democratic … 1981-11-16    11 -1.48         10       1       28
#>  8 117765 Congo, Democratic … 1981-12-16    12 -0.388        10       1       28
#>  9 100468 Namibia             1980-01-16     1 -1.96         12       4       52
#> 10 100468 Namibia             1980-02-15     2  0.557        12       4       52
#> # … with 24 more rows
```

Data used:

```
crops <- structure(list(gid = c("117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
"117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
"117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", 
"117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "117765", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", "100468", 
"100468", "100468", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", 
"117770", "117770", "117770", "117770", "117770"), country = c("Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", "Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)", 
"Congo, Democratic Republic of (Zaire)"), Time = structure(c(3667, 
3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 3819, 3849, 3880, 3911, 3941, 3972, 4002, 
4033, 4063, 4092, 4123, 4153, 4184, 4214, 4245, 4276, 4306, 4337, 
4367, 3667, 3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 3819, 3849, 3880, 3911, 3941, 
3972, 4002, 4033, 4063, 4092, 4123, 4153, 4184, 4214, 4245, 4276, 
4306, 4337, 4367, 3667, 3697, 3727, 3758, 3788, 3819, 3849, 3880, 
3911, 3941, 3972, 4002, 4033, 4063, 4092, 4123, 4153, 4184, 4214, 
4245, 4276, 4306, 4337, 4367), class = "Date"), Month = c("01", 
"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", 
"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", 
"12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", 
"11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
"10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
"09", "10", "11", "12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
"08", "09", "10", "11", "12"), SPEI1 = c(-0.702853560447693, 
2.77506303787231, -1.38380765914917, -0.474617034196854, 0.610002398490906, 
-0.389719426631927, 2.31887650489807, 1.47994863986969, 1.66277933120728, 
0.399970233440399, -1.47139978408813, -0.435711354017258, -0.510784149169922, 
-1.15937781333923, 0.523077189922333, -0.161062479019165, -0.481528997421265, 
-1.71726500988007, -1.77663195133209, 0.765306115150452, -0.774405002593994, 
-0.197176232933998, -1.47615599632263, -0.388415157794952, -1.95947802066803, 
0.557283878326416, 1.77989518642426, -1.2029390335083, -0.119278997182846, 
1.44610369205475, -1.4578732252121, -1.14002466201782, 1.1647777557373, 
-1.34318947792053, -0.500527501106262, 1.50793671607971, -1.45792877674103, 
-2.00679230690002, -1.51340460777283, -1.9636687040329, -1.40127754211426, 
-0.182968750596046, 0.295145452022552, 0.630711793899536, -0.166128441691399, 
-0.55840003490448, -2.62139987945557, -1.74482023715973, 0.649401307106018, 
1.423499584198, -2.04273128509521, 0.271935135126114, 0.616238355636597, 
-1.03605198860168, 1.6733535528183, 1.78166878223419, 1.87084305286407, 
1.10145688056946, -1.23061907291412, -1.64128601551056, -1.00736439228058, 
-1.91670513153076, 1.09841585159302, 0.464365869760513, 1.01759243011475, 
-1.08844792842865, -0.508061945438385, -0.196570366621017, -0.805905878543854, 
0.117944374680519, -0.862984955310822, -1.63738548755646), growstart = c(10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5), growend = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12), maincrop = c(28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 
52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -72L))
```

Comment: Thanks ! In my entire dataset, I have some NAs. I need to keep them. However, your code does not work with NAs. what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be using some checks between.

If you want to use this on the whole dataset you group by crop.

```
df |> 
    filter(ifelse(growstart > growend,
                  between(as.numeric(Month), 1, min(growend)) | between(as.numeric(Month), min(growstart), 12),
                  between(as.numeric(Month), 1, min(growend)) & between(as.numeric(Month), min(growstart), 12)))
```

```
      gid country       Time      SPEI1 growstart growend maincrop Month
1  100468 Namibia 1980-01-16 -1.9594780        12       4       52    01
2  100468 Namibia 1980-02-15  0.5572839        12       4       52    02
3  100468 Namibia 1980-03-16  1.7798952        12       4       52    03
4  100468 Namibia 1980-04-16 -1.2029390        12       4       52    04
5  100468 Namibia 1980-12-16  1.5079367        12       4       52    12
6  100468 Namibia 1981-01-16 -1.4579288        12       4       52    01
7  100468 Namibia 1981-02-15 -2.0067923        12       4       52    02
8  100468 Namibia 1981-03-16 -1.5134046        12       4       52    03
9  100468 Namibia 1981-04-16 -1.9636687        12       4       52    04
10 100468 Namibia 1981-12-16 -1.7448202        12       4       52    12
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. It produces 0 observation.

Comment: It worked with every dataset you gave.